# How to use checkbox filter on smart table?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How to use checkbox filter on smart table??
here is my code,When user click the check box,it show firstName is'Sam' record only. Here is my code:

```
angular.module('smarttabledemo', ['smart-table']).run(function() {
  console.clear();
})
.controller('smarttabledemo', function($scope) {
  $scope.data = [
    { firstName: 'Sam', lastName: 'Evans', phone: 'Not Provide', hometown: 'Anytown, ST' },
    { firstName: 'Saul', lastName: 'Evans', phone: '555-555-1234', hometown: 'Anytown, ST' },
    { firstName: 'Charlie', lastName: 'Anders', phone: '555-555-9876', hometown: 'Springfield, ST' },
    { firstName: 'Jessica', lastName: 'Cortez', phone: 'Not Provide', hometown: 'Springfield, ST' },
    { firstName: 'Amy', lastName: 'Wood', phone: '555-555-1348', hometown: 'Metroville, ST' },
  ]
})


<div class='container' ng-app='smarttabledemo' ng-controller='smarttabledemo'>
  <h3>Minimal Angular/Smart-Table Demo</h3>
  <table st-table='data' class='table'>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th colspan='999'>
          <input st-search class='form-control' type='search' placeholder='Search' ng-model='search' />
        </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th st-sort='firstName'>First Name</th>
        <th st-sort='lastName'>Last Name</th>
        <th st-sort='phone'>Phone Number</th>
        <th st-sort='hometown'>Hometown</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr st-select-row='row' ng-repeat='row in data'>
        <td>{{row.firstName}}</td>
        <td>{{row.lastName}}</td>
        <td>{{row.phone}}</td>
        <td>{{row.hometown}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

I try to use the following code for filter, but not success.

```
  Just Show Sam:  <input st-search="firstName" ng-model="a" type="checkbox" ng-true-value="'Sam'" ng-false-value="''" value="{{a}}">
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kr7bonc8/)

Comment: you want to filter a single name or multiple names?

Comment: single name, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can pass filter option in ng-repeat like this `ng-repeat='row in tableData | filter:a'` and set value of checkbox "Sam" like this `<input st-search="firstName" ng-model="a" type="checkbox" ng-true-value="'Sam'" ng-false-value="''" value="Sam">` your updated fiddle [Link](https://jsfiddle.net/kr7bonc8/2/)